# R save images to create animation of plot incrementally generated with large number of points

Tags: r, animation, graphics, plot

I'm trying to create an animation based on a scatter plot that is incrementally built up over time.  The use case is that I have a database of about 2 million points with timestamps for each, and want to generate frames that show all the points at or before a specific date.

Without saving the images, I'm able to do this by first calling `plot()`, and then having a for loop that incrementally draws the data for each successive day using the `points()` function.

When I try to save images using the code below, I get an error of "plot.new has not been called yet".  As I understand, `dev.off()` is needed to save image, but that also closes the device that is being drawn to.  Is there a way to get around this?  Having to re-plot the data for every frame isn't much of an option due to the size of the data.

```
plot(info$lon, info$lat, xlim=c(0,30), ylim=c(30,60))
for (i in c(1:length(allDates))){
    filename=paste(sprintf('%05d', i), ".png", sep="")  
    png(filename=fileName)
    # (code that gets the data for a particular date via a database query)
    points(info$lon, info$lat, cex=0.1)
    dev.off()
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The comment by @roman-lustrik about `ggsave()` was what I was looking for, and results in the code below:

```
plotObj = ggplot(...) + geom_point() + xlim(...) + ylim(...)
for (i in c(1:length(allDates))){
    filename=paste(sprintf('%05d', i), ".png", sep="")  
    # (code that gets the data for a particular date via a database query)
    plotObj = plotObj + geom_point(data=info, aes(x=lon, y=lat), size=0.5)
    print(plotObj)
    ggsave(filename=filename, width=6, height=6)
}
```

However, this is still a bit slow, so my current solution to render images quickly is to use the code similar to the original, but where I just use `plot()` to render frames with data for a single date (using a transparent background).  To progressively stack up the images, I then use a bash script which uses the imagemagick `convert -composite` command to blend two images together.  This blended image is then blended with the image from the next date, and so on, until the final image shows all of the data:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $files
do
    convert $prevFile $i -composite ./stackedImages/$i
    prevFile=./stackedImages/$i
done
```

Comment: All the plots you want to save in the png file have to be created between the function `png` and `dev.off`.
The error tells you that no `plot` has been called between png and dev.off so that the points function cannot add `points` to any plot.

Comment: Is there a way then to save the contents of the previous plot so that it is available after `dev.off()` is called?  To speed up the code, I'd like to set things up so that each iteration of the loop only draws a few points on top of the previous plot, instead of having to draw millions of points each time.

Comment: If you use `ggplot2` to create images, you can use `ggsave` to save the last image produced.

Comment: `ggsave` seems to be what I need.  I've modified my code to first do `plotObj = ggplot(...)`, and then in the loop, do `plotObj = plotObj + geom_point(...)`, `print(plotObj)`, and then `ggsave(...)`.  It's still a bit slow (a few seconds per saved image), and I've come up with a faster implementation where I use `plot` to create transparent images per each day, and then use a bash command with imagemagick to blend the images together.

Comment: If you want to go down the path of `knitr`, you can create an animation fairly easy. See ani.pdf (and source ani.Rnw) here: https://github.com/romunov/Homemade You will have to use Acrobat Reader to view the animation.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood, you want to get several png files with different number of points on it, and with the first points created by `plot(info$lon, info$lat, xlim=c(0,30), ylim=c(30,60))`.

You can do that instead :

```
temp1 <- info$lon
temp2 <- info$lat
for (i in c(1:length(allDates))){
        filename=paste(sprintf('%05d', i), ".png", sep="")  
        png(filename=fileName)
        plot(temp1, temp2, xlim=c(0,30), ylim=c(30,60))
        # (code that gets the data for a particular date via a database query)
        points(info$lon, info$lat, cex=0.1)
        dev.off()
        temp1 <- c(temp1,info$lon)
        temp2 <- c(temp2,info$lat)
}
```

Comment: Not quite - that code will just plot the data from two different days.  What I'm trying to do is have frame 1 be the data from day 1, frame 2 be day 1 and 2, frame 3 be 1,2,3, etc.  So, the last frame of the movie would just be a scatter plot of all the data.  The problem with calling `plot` in the loop is that towards the end, I'm plotting millions of points each iteration and the code becomes incredibly slow.  I'm trying to figure out a way to avoid that by stacking new data points on top of old data points.

Comment: As I thought, I hadn't really understood.
I have updated my code.

Comment: And now, does it answer your question ?

Comment: Your modified code still has the same issue of having to replot all of the data from the previous days.  What I'm trying to do is keep the graphics device open so that I don't have to keep redrawing everything for every iteration of the loop.  I'm rendering about 2000 frames for  2 million data points, and with your code, each iteration of the loop gets progressively slower, until it takes several minutes to create a single plot, and the whole code may take a day or more to run.  The update I've made to the original question shows a much quicker implementation that I'm currently using.