# Creating animation in R

Tags: r, animation

I'm looking at the possibilities for animation creation in R. The {Animation} package seems to be mainly an R platform for ffmpeg and imagemagick.  The only reference I found to creating individual image frames is to nest `plot()` inside a loop.  But this seems an unfeasibly slow process for producing more complex plots given the poor speed performance of the `png()` renderer, particularly for plots including map objects - for example:

```
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)    
starttime = Sys.time()
for(i in 1:10){
  png(paste('frames/', i, '.png', sep=''))
  plot(wrld_simpl, col='grey85', bg = 'white', border='white')
  points(sample(-180:180, 50), sample(-90:90, 50), col='red', pch=16, cex=2)
  title('poxy map')
  dev.off()
}
print(Sys.time() - starttime)
```

yielding 10 frames and:

```
Time difference of 9.763794 secs
```

I don't understand why R is so slow at rendering - at this rate it would take 45 mins or so to render a 2 minute video at 25fps, which seems slow for this relatively simple map example. Wrapping with `apply` is no quicker. Does anyone know of a way to wrap `plot` more efficiently, or perhaps to save a plot midway after the unchanging elements have been rendered?

Comment: Although I've just spotted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611456/r-save-images-to-create-animation-of-plot-incrementally-generated-with-large-num?rq=1) so my question may be a duplicate.

Comment: `plot(wrld_simpl)` is actually plotting a lot of segments... you might want to convert it to a raster layer somehow; rasterImage should be much more efficient still with a decent resolution.

Comment: Fair enough. I just recognise there is still a lot of duplication in reloading it. Comments elsewhere suggest `ggplot2::ggsave` is a way to achieve this, which I'll looking into.

Comment: `ggplot2` will be much slower than base graphics, I reckon, and ggsave is simply a wrapper around `png(); dev.off()` so it will be slower too.

Comment: You can use `grid.raster` it as faster as `rasterImage` Hope that @baptiste undelete his answer combining `animation` and `grid.raster`.

Comment: @agstudy i was very disappointed that the animation froze after posting :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plotting the map as an image with just enough resolution should be more efficient than the plot method for SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

```
require(maps) # save the world
png("world.png", width=500, height=200)
map("world", col="grey90", fill=TRUE, border="grey90",  mar=c(0,0,0,0))
dev.off()

library(png); library(grid)
img = readPNG("world.png") 

animation::saveGIF( {
  for( ii in 1:100) {
    grid.newpage()
    grid.raster(img)
    grid.points(default.units="npc")
  }
  }, ani.height=200, ani.width=500)
```

[image]

Comment: This is useful if you think you can escape from base graphics. I'm not so sure.  But I'm wondering if `animation` can utilise its imageMagick to overlay 'data' images over a basemap, and that be more efficient? [This technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917250/image-magick-overlaying-images) looks quite promising.

Comment: same works in base graphics, I'm just more comfortable with grid. But yeah, if you don't need axes etc. imagemagick will be better. (animation now working in my browser, how odd...)